# DATEDIFF function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, datediff

I need to use Oracle but DATEDIFF function doesn't work in Oracle DB.

How to write the following code in Oracle? I saw some examples using INTERVAL or TRUNC.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ('2000-01-01','2000-01-02') AS DateDiff;
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In Oracle, you can simply subtract two dates and get the difference in **days**. Also note that unlike SQL Server or MySQL, in Oracle you cannot perform a `select` statement without a `from` clause. One way around this is to use the builtin dummy table, `dual`:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2000-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  
       TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DateDiff
FROM   dual
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try it tomorrow coz I only have SQL server in my computer. Thanks again for your time and explanation~  :)

Answer (score 11):

Just subtract the two dates:

```
select date '2000-01-02' - date '2000-01-01' as dateDiff
from dual;
```

The result will be the difference in days.

More details are in the manual:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i48042

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try it tomorrow coz I only have SQL server in my computer. Thanks again for your time n the link~ :)

Comment: @user3601310: what's a `tomorrow coz`? (coz sounds like the german word for "vomitting" .... )

Answer (score 6):

You can simply subtract two dates. You have to cast it first, using `to_date`:

```
select to_date('2000-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
       - to_date('2000-01-02', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
       datediff
from   dual
;
```

The result is in days, to the difference of these two dates is `-1` (you could swap the two dates if you like). If you like to have it in hours, just multiply the result with 24.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try it tomorrow coz I only have SQL server in my computer. Thanks again for your time and explanation~ :)

Answer (score 0):

We can directly subtract dates to get difference in Days.

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;
    DECLARE
        V_VAR NUMBER;
    BEGIN
         V_VAR:=TO_DATE('2000-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') ;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_VAR);
    END;
```