# How to count the number of days between dates

Tags: sql, oracle

Im currently working on a project and the output im looking for, i need to count the number of days between an appointment and operation, currently i have this

```
Select Patient_FirstName ||' '|| Patient_surname "Patient Name", appointment_date, OPeration_date, datediff(Appointment_Date,Operation_Date) "Days till operation"
from PatientRecord p , Patient b, Appointment a, Operation o
where p.patient_ID = b.Patient_ID
and p.appointment_ID = a.appointment_ID
and p.operation_ID = o.OPeration_ID
order by Patient_Surname;
```

which is just returning an invalid identifier ,

when i round months it works fine, but i need days

```
Select Patient_FirstName ||' '|| Patient_surname "Patient Name", appointment_date, OPeration_date, Round (months_between(Appointment_Date,Operation_Date)) "Days till operation"
from PatientRecord p , Patient b, Appointment a, Operation o
where p.patient_ID = b.Patient_ID
and p.appointment_ID = a.appointment_ID
and p.operation_ID = o.OPeration_ID
order by Patient_Surname;
```

thats what i have for rounding months, is there something similar i can do for days?

Comment: Simply do `Appointment_Date - Operation_Date` to get the difference in days.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406397/datediff-function-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

First, *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

In Oracle, you can just subtract the dates:

```
Select Patient_FirstName ||' '|| Patient_surname as "Patient Name",
       appointment_date, Operation_date,
       trunc(Operation_Date - Appointment_Date) as "Days till operation"
from PatientRecord pr join
     Patient p
     on pr.patient_ID = p.Patient_ID join
     Appointment a
     on pr.appointment_ID = a.appointment_ID join
     Operation o
     on pr.operation_ID = o.Operation_ID
order by Patient_Surname;
```

Comment: that trunc function worked thanks very much, in regards to the from clause, when i did the join syntax it didnt return the proper data but my original code did?

Comment: `Patient p` should be `Patient b` (and the join condition needs fixing). Also, this does not consider when the appointment and operation have time components and are, for example, actually 2 days 21 hours apart but on the calendar this would be a difference of 3 days.

Comment: Why  can not use "comma" syntax ? Oracle before version 9 not support "join" syntax ...

Comment: @Mike . . . Oracle 9 supported explicit `JOIN`.  Oracle 8 did not.

Answer (score 0):

If the `appointment_date` is `2017-01-01 14:30:00` and the `operation_date` is `2017-01-04 09:30:00` then the difference is 2 days and 21 hours but you probably want this to be compared as the difference between `2017-01-01` and `2017-01-04` and displayed as 3 days (rather than 2) so:

```
Select Patient_FirstName ||' '|| Patient_surname AS "Patient Name",
       appointment_date,
       OPeration_date,
       TRUNC( Operation_Date ) - TRUNC ( Appointment_Date ) AS "Days till operation"
from   PatientRecord p
       INNER JOIN Patient b
       ON ( p.patient_ID = b.Patient_ID )
       INNER JOIN Appointment a
       ON ( p.appointment_ID = a.appointment_ID )
       INNER JOIN Operation o
       ON ( p.operation_ID = o.OPeration_ID )
order by Patient_Surname;
```

You could also use:

```
CEIL( Operation_Date - Appointment_Date ) AS "Days till operation"
```

Comment: the inner join function works, thanks again helped alot :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
Select DateDiff(d,Appointment_Date,Operation_Date) as [Days till operation]
```

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATEDIFF` function.