# SQL to find difference of dates - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table:

table1

```
tran_id    user_id    start_date    end_date
1          100        01-04-2018    02-04-2018
2          100        14-06-2018    14-06-2018
4          100        12-06-2018    12-06-2018
7          101        05-01-2018    05-01-2018
9          101        08-01-2018    08-01-2018
3          101        03-01-2018    03-01-2018
```

Date format is `DD-MM-YYYY`

I need to find the day difference ordered by `user_id` and `start_date`. The formula to find day difference is to subtract `end_date` of the prior record and `start_date` of the next.

Here is the expected output:

```
tran_id    user_id    start_date    end_date       day_diff
1          100        01-04-2018    02-04-2018     71
4          100        12-06-2018    12-06-2018     2
2          100        14-06-2018    14-06-2018     0

3          101        03-01-2018    03-01-2018     2
7          101        05-01-2018    05-01-2018     3
9          101        08-01-2018    08-01-2018     0
```

How to get this in an SQL query?

Comment: "Date format is `DD-MM-YYYY`" - do you mean columns type is not  `DATE` ? Why?

Comment: It is date. The format is DD-MM-YYYY in the question I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `lead()` to find next value, then substract dates:

```
select tran_id, user_id, start_date, end_date, nvl(nsd - start_date, 0) diff
  from (
    select t.*, lead(start_date) over (partition by user_id 
                                       order by start_date) nsd 
      from table1 t)
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2b822fef22d6e6831d94e2ff8b87a922)</sup>**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()` for this.  Because `lead()` takes three arguments, you don't need a subquery or to deal with `null` values:

```
select t.*,
       (lead(start_date, 1, start_date) over (partition by user_id order by start_date) -
        start_date
       ) as diff
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this: [DATEDIFF function in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406477/4119964) in combination with the [LAG function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

A minor correction to the answer given by Ponder Stibbons. Difference highlighted in **Bold**.

select tran_id, user_id, start_date, end_date, nvl(nsd - **end_date**, 0) diff
  from (
    select t.*, lead(start_date) over (partition by user_id 
                                       order by start_date) nsd 
      from date_test t);

Regards
Akash