# Subtracting Dates ORA 01722

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to subtract two dates and get a `integer` value in return. I have seem to hit a roadblock since one of the two dates is null which subsequently returns an error. Is there any workaround to this, I covet to get the aging_date instead if the review_date is null.

```
select to_date(sysdate)aging_date,to_char(review_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')review_date
from mytable    

aging_date           review_date
2/26/2020             01/05/2020
2/26/2020             05/15/2018
2/26/2020                
2/26/2020             03/14/2019
2/26/2020             12/17/2019

select aging_date,review_date,(aging_date - review_date)actual_date from
(
select 
to_date(sysdate)aging_date,to_char(review_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')review_date, 
(aging_date - review_date)actual_date from mytable
)new

ORA 01722: Invalid Number
```

Comment: Can this resolve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406397/datediff-function-in-oracle ?

Comment: @TDuong, the issue is that there is `NULL` in the review_date column.

Comment: SYSDATE is a **date** and therefore doesn't require a `to_date()` conversion. Likewise, according to your comment, REVIEW_DATE is apparently a string and so doesn't require a `to_char()` conversion. Wouldn't it have been simpler and less confusing to everybody if you had just posted the DDL for `mytable` (or a redacted test case version of it)?

Comment: But doesn't `sysdate` return a timestamp datatype?

Comment: @JakeWagner - no: ["The data type of the returned value is DATE"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYSDATE.html). But even if you had a timestamp - say from `systimestamp` - you wouldn't use `to_date()` to convert it, you would `cast()` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must convert the `varchar2`  column in `DATE` column.

```
select aging_date,review_date,
(aging_date - to_date(review_date,'mm/dd/yyyy')) actual_date 
from tab;

AGING_DATE          REVIEW_DAT ACTUAL_DATE
------------------- ---------- -----------
26.02.2020 00:00:00 01/05/2020          52
26.02.2020 00:00:00 05/15/2018         652
26.02.2020 00:00:00                       
26.02.2020 00:00:00 03/14/2019         349
26.02.2020 00:00:00 12/17/2019          71
```

**Subtracting `DATE` and `VARCHAR2` leads to an `ORA-01722: invalid number`**

```
select aging_date,review_date,
(aging_date - review_date) actual_date 
from tab;

-- fails with
-- ORA-01722: invalid number

-- DDL
CREATE TABLE  TAB
   ("AGING_DATE" DATE, 
    "REVIEW_DATE" VARCHAR2(10)
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to select the aging date, review date and the `difference = (aging_date - review_date)`. The query selects the `aging_date` and the review date, and for the date difference, The case statement calculates the difference only when `aging_date` and `review_date` are not `null`. You can also use the `if - end if` block instead of case here:

```
select 
aging_date,
review_date,
(case when aging_date is not null and review_date is not null then (aging_date - review_date) end )actual_date  
from mytable;
```

Comment: The goal is to select the aging date, review date and the difference =  (aging_date - review_date).

The query selects the aging_date and the review date and for the date difference, 
The case statement calculates the difference only when aging_date and  review_date are not null. You can also use the if - end if block instead of case here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  should return a zero value if there is no review_date (just subtracting aging_date  from itself)

```
select aging_date,
       review_date,
       (aging_date - nvl(review_date,aging_date)) actual_date from mytable
```

documentation on the [NVL](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php) function.

Comment: Thanks @OldProgrammer, unfortunately it still returns the same pesky `ORA 01722` error.

Comment: what are the data types of aging_date and review_date?  Are they DATE or something else?

Comment: review_date has `to_char` prefix and the aging_date is just the `to_date(sysdate)` meaning today's date.

Comment: OK so what is the data type of review_date in the table???  you are omitting some details I fear.  Please edit the question and show the table definition.

Comment: The question has been fully edited to portray old `data_type` changes.

Comment: @JakeWagner - "The question has been fully edited to portray old data_type changes" No it has not.  I see no DDL showing the actual data types of the referenced columns.  Only your treatment of them, which may or may not be correct and reflective of the actual data types.