# How to substract 2 dates to get number of days

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to substract 2 dates to get number of days, which I will divide later by number of days in year. The INC_DATE is in date format, the to_date function is used to define date from 1.1. of the selected year. Year 2015 is defined because the output value (days) should not take year from inc_date, therefore even if inc_date has different years, I have defined it as default year 2015.

```
case when (extract(month from inc_date)=2 and extract(day from inc_date)=29) then
(to_date(inc_date,’2015/mm/dd’) - to_date (’2015-01-01’,’yy/mm/dd’))/366 else
(to_date(inc_date,’2015/mm/dd’) - to_date (’2015-01-01’,’yy/mm/dd’))/365
end as E1
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then sql developer 4.2

Comment: So should this be tagged [tag:oracle-sqldeveloper]?

Comment: What is not working with your current code?  Does [DATEDIFF function in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28406397) answer your question?

Comment: Yes sorry, Oracle SQL developer, I am newbie in this....datediff is not recognized function when I tried

Comment: SQL Developer is just a desktop application and it is not relevant for code questions unless you are having issues with the tool itself. For Oracle SQL questions please tag Oracle and SQL.

Comment: Is INC_DATE an actual date value (column is defined as `DATE` etc) or is it a string that looks like one? If it's a date then you should use `trunc` etc and never `to_date` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATEDIFF` function to subtract between dates and get the difference in days, months, or years in Sql Server.
like below Example- -

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime = '01 Jan 2020'
DECLARE @ToDate datetime = '31 Mar 2023'
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @FromDate, @ToDate) AS NoOfDays
SELECT DATEDIFF(Month, @FromDate, @ToDate) AS NoOfMonths
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, @FromDate, @ToDate) AS NoOfYears
```